# Hide legend items if value is equal to 0 in NVD3.js Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Looking to hide `label` from `legend` of a Pie Chart when return `value` is equal to `0`. Can anyone point me in the right direction in NVD3.js?

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
    var donutChart = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function (d) {
            return d.label
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return d.value
        })

        d3.select("#chart-devices svg")
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(1200)
        .call(donutChart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(donutChart.update);
    return donutChart;
});
```

Comment: I think the best you can do is to remove preliminarily data items with value = 0.

Comment: However here is a fiddle trying to remove item (with "zero" value) from legend: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/yt7vrohk/

Comment: Thank you very much @beaver. I am getting an error of `Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`. I also wondered if perhaps adding a class to hide the legend items equal to `0`. The solution posted works great with a few items, yet with many, there are obvious gaps.

Comment: I can't see any error on my jsfiddle. Share your code

Comment: i don't know why in your case renderEvent handler doesn't work. So I changed it to setTimeout(): https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/8hpekad6/

Comment: That is great and fixed this error. When selecting a legend item it is bringing the hidden ones back. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible answer is to remove items with value=0 on `renderEnd` event:

```
chart.dispatch.on('renderEnd', function () {
    console.log("renderEnd");
    d3.selectAll(".nv-legend .nv-series")[0].forEach(function (d) {
        //get the data
        var t = d3.select(d).data()[0];
        // remove item from legend
        if (t.value == 0)
            d3.select(d).remove();
    });
});
```

Another possibility is to remove items after a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    d3.selectAll(".nv-legend .nv-series")[0].forEach(function (d) {
        //get the data
        var t = d3.select(d).data()[0];
        // remove item from legend
        if (t.value == 0)
            d3.select(d).remove();
    });
}, 1);
```

In both cases there are gaps among remaining items.

Here is a fiddle (first option): https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/yt7vrohk/

Comment: is there any way to fill the spaces left by the removed legend?